# Centering div in h1

Tags: html, css, header, anchor, center

I'm trying to create a portfolio for freecodecamp, however I can't find out how to center the button, and or div labeled "row" on the page. I need the row div as I will later be adding more buttons, but for now I only need the FCC button. Below are both my html and css files for my site so far. Any help is welcome!

HTML:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<!-- Web page starts here -->
<body id="body">
  <section id="land">
      <h1 id="mpp" class="text-center"> My Personal Portfolio </h1>
        <div class="row" id="btnrow">
          <a href="http://www.freecodecamp.com/zacmelendez" class="btn responsive" id="fcc"><i class="fa fa-file-code-o"> Free Code Camp</i></a>
        </div>
  </section>
  <section id="intro">
  </section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#mpp {
  font-family: Monospace;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 15%;
  margin: 0;
}
#land {
  background: url(http://img.hrhwalls.com/images2/ki13j11c4ef.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#fcc {
  background-color: #016403;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 17px;
  position: inherit;
}
#btnrow {
  right: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#btnrow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Should do the trick. See working example below

```css
#body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#mpp {
  font-family: Monospace;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 15%;
  margin: 0;
}
#land {
  background: url(http://img.hrhwalls.com/images2/ki13j11c4ef.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#fcc {
  background-color: #016403;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 17px;
  position: inherit;
}
#btnrow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<!-- Web page starts here -->
<body id="body">
  <section id="land">
      <h1 id="mpp" class="text-center"> My Personal Portfolio </h1>
        <div class="row" id="btnrow">
          <a href="http://www.freecodecamp.com/zacmelendez" class="btn responsive" id="fcc"><i class="fa fa-file-code-o"> Free Code Camp</i></a>
        </div>
  </section>
  <section id="intro">
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: So that does make it centered, however, when I change to browser size, the button size increases. I've tried width, but its the same thing. Is there any way to make the button the width of the text?

Comment: Nevermind! Used a set pixel width and it seems to be working! Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You could give the div a width and use margin auto for the left and right values, this will center the element horizontally.

```
.row {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px; /*or any measurement*/
}
```